# how to start a new line in __str__()

Tags: python-2.7

```
name = "1"
accountnumber = "1"
balance = "1"
msg = "your name is: " + name + "your accountnumber is: " + accountnumber + "your balance is: " + balance
print msg
```

**the output is:**
your name is: 1your accountnumber is: 1your balance is: 1

**but I want this:**
your name is: 1
your accountnumber is: 1
your balance is: 1

how to modify the code? I think the msg = part should be modified.

Comment: Try using '+' instead of commas

Comment: "+" has no linebreak effect here

Comment: it does if you add '\n' to your string. See my updated answer.

Comment: msg = "your name is: ", '\n', name.....you meant it like this? it does not work.

Comment: No, you are still using commas instead of plus signs. it should be `msg = "your name is: " + name + "\n" ... Also, the '\n' needs to come after name, accountnumber & balance, not before them

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
msg = "your name is: ", '\n', name + "your accountnumber is: " + accountnumber + "your balance is: " + balance
```

to this:

```
msg = "your name is: " + name + "\nyour accountnumber is: " + accountnumber + "\nyour balance is: " + balance
```

Defining `msg` with commas is creating a list of strings, rather than formatting output like you want. The way you are casting `msg` is not the same as:

```
print "your name is: ", '\n', name + "your accountnumber is: " + accountnumber + "your balance is: " + balance
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, consider marking it as correct. Thanks